# React Native Swift callback issues returning array or object

Tags: swift, react-native

I am trying to pass an array or object in the callback however on the React Native side I am getting a result back as null. I am able to pass back strings and dictionary but not an array or object

devices returns the following

```
[InputEndpoint(name: "device 1", uniqueID: 431431039), InputEndpoint(name: "Bus 2", uniqueID: -392242504), InputEndpoint(name: "Bus 3", uniqueID: 1406826593)]
```

```
@objc
  func getInputDevices(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
// devices is an array
    let devices = midiManager.endpoints.inputs
    callback([devices])
  }
```

Also have issue with the follow

```
@objc
  func getInputDevices(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    let devices = ["name": "sometime", "id": 0]
    callback([devices])
  }
```

Need help with sending an array back to js side

Bridging header

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ReactNativeMidiKit,RCTEventEmitter)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getInputDevices:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end
```